# "read access to unsupported AArch64 system register" when starting Ubuntu on qemu (ARM64)

Tags: 16.04, virtualization, qemu, arm64

I would like to run the Ubuntu installer in *qemu*. I have used the kernel from the respective Ubuntu CD images and have verified my command line using the AMD64 architecture:

```
$ qemu-system-x86_64 --version
QEMU emulator version 2.5.0 ..
$ isoinfo -R -x "/install/vmlinuz" -i bionic-server-amd64.iso >linux
$ qemu-system-x86_64 -nodefaults -nographic -kernel linux \
   -serial stdio -append "console=ttyS0" \
   -machine pc -cpu qemu64 -m 1G
[    0.0000000] Linux version 4.15.0-44-generic ..
```

However, when I try the same thing for ARM64 architecture (not my host arch):

```
$ qemu-system-aarch64 --version
QEMU emulator version 2.5.0 ..
$ isoinfo -R -x "/install/vmlinuz" -i bionic-server-arm64.iso >linux
$ qemu-system-aarch64 -nodefaults -nographic -kernel linux \
   -serial stdio -append "console=ttyAMA0" \
   -machine virt -cpu cortex-a53 -m 1G
```

I get zero output at 100% cpu usage. **How can i determine what went wrong?**

Executing with `-d unimp -D debug.log` reveals:

```
read access to unsupported AArch64 system register op0:3 op1:0 crn:0 crm:7 op2:2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just upgrade your system.**

Both AMD64 and ARM64 kernels start exactly as attempted in question using `QEMU emulator version 3.1.0`

Note that the command line is not exactly the same though, `console=ttyS0` translates to `console=ttyAMA0` on ARM. To really start *subiquity*, add `-initrd initrd -cdrom bionic-server-arm64.iso`

- extract using `isoinfo -R -x "/install/initrd.gz" -i bionic-server-arm64.iso >initrd` (verify results - *isoinfo* will not fail verbosely)
- loading from ISO will be slow, adding virtio & more cores may result in significant speedup
- when adding a *preseed* file, note the cdrom mount location, e.g. `file=/cdrom/preseed/example.seed`